# VBA excel, if Cells(counter,1)="text" then

Tags: vba, if-statement, text, range, cells

I'm trying to execute an if statement that only activates if a certain cell contains a specific text. The cell in question needs to be dynamically altered based on a integer that will change, so far ive tried multiple methods but nothing seems to work.

```
If Cells(counter, 1).text = "text" then

If Cells(counter, 1).value = "text" then

If Range(Cells(counter, 1)).text = "text then

If Range(Cells(counter, 1)).value = "text then
```

This seems like a simple procedure, does someone have a solution?

Thanks, Sporre

Edit:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_Change() 
If CheckBox.Value = True Then 
   'do stuff 
End If 
ElseIf CheckBox.Value = False Then 
    If Cells(1, counter).Value = "text1" Or Cells(1, counter).Value = 
    "text2" Or Cells(1, counter).Value = "text3" Then
       'do stuff 
    End If 
End If 
End Sub
```

This is where i get the error message "Application-definded or Object-defined error".

Edit 2:
The problem was I tried to call for the counter in several different subs and it was not a public integer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code `If Cells(i, 1).value = "text" Then` should work. However, you should post some more code, as it is unclear what makes the code run. Is it manually executed, or should it run on Worksheet_Change, etc?

Comment: Okay, so I've got it to work when i activate the worksheet, however it doesn't work when a checkbox changes to false. The only difference is I have multple statements in the IF statement, as in :    If Cells(i, 1).value = "text1" or Cells(i, 1).value = "text2" then

Comment: Try posting a bit more code. The error does not originate from the `If` statement you've posted.

Comment: `Private Sub UT_Change()
If UT.Value = True Then
 'do stuff

End If 

ElseIf UT.Value = False Then

    
     If Cells(1, counter).Value = "text1" Or Cells(1, counter).Value = "text2" Or Cells(1, counter).Value = "text3" Then

          'do stuff

      End If 

End If

End Sub`
Sorry, cant seem to get the formatting right

Comment: Try editing your original post, instead of posting it as a comment. You should also specify what `UT.Value` is.

Comment: Either you `counter` is not a number or it is <=0. Check it with `Debug.Print counter`. Or at least tell us how it is defined and assigned?

Comment: it is defined as DIm counter as Integer and assigned the value 1 as the UserForm is activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `End If` and then follow up with and `ElseIf`. The first one ends the `If` statement entirely, meaning that the you would have to begin a new one. Based on you edit, I think your code should look something like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_Change()
    If CheckBox.Value = True Then
       'do stuff
    ElseIf CheckBox.Value = False Then
        If (Counter < 1) Then
            'Show an error if the counter is less than 1
            MsgBox "Error: Counter less than 1", vbCritical
        ElseIf Cells(1, counter).Value = "text1" Or Cells(1, counter).Value = "text2" Or Cells(1, counter).Value = "text3" Then
           'do stuff
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Still the same problem, it higlights the line with the Cells(1, counter).value="text1" etc and gives me the same error message

Comment: The issue might be your `Counter`. I have tried adding a simple check for its value, to the code. It does not handle all scenarios though.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was I tried to call for the counter in several different subs and it was not a public integer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This one will work

```
if (Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 1).Value)="text") Then
```

Comment: When I try it i get an error message: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
If Worksheets("Name of your worksheet").Cells(counter, 1).Value)="text" Then
    'execute some code
End if
```